finiteness of quotient map
I am new to algebraic space s and stacks. My question is the following:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $G$ be a group scheme acting on $X$. We have the natural map $\pi : X \to X/G$. When $\pi$ will be a finite morphism?

In particular do we have any characterisation of the action or the group for which we always have finite morphism?


Thanks in advance.

What is "$X/G$" for you?

@abx $X/G$ is algebraic space

No. Not without strong conditions on the action.

@abx What kind of condition I have to take?

I don't know what situation you have in mind. A theorem of Keel-Mori guarantees the existence of $X/G$ if the action is proper with finite stabilizers. But of course in that case $\pi$ is finite only if $G$ is finite.
